# Prevent ApplyTemplate() from being called during Measuring phase

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-4.0

I'm currently in the process of creating a virtualized TreeView control for an application I'm working on. My current implementation relies on an optimized measuring algorithm which is giving me some issues. Now before I get into the details here note that I'm using .NET version 4.0.

What I've done to optimize the measuring of the internal **TreeView** control is minimize the work being done in the **MeasureOverride()** function. I've got it down to the bare essentials and what I'm left with now is an expensive call deep in the guts of WPF. Basically Calling **Measure()** on a control applies all templates on the sub controls which is really expensive. Since my TreeViewItems will all have a defined Height I don't really need the template during the Measuring phase. Does anyone know of a way to bypass the **ApplyTemplates()** call?

Here's a sample call stack

- MyCustomControl.MeasureOverride(...)

  - ...

    - UIElement.Measure(...)

      - FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(...)

        - FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate(...) <-- Expensive!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to avoid the `ApplyTemplate()` call in your specific case, but you shouldn't need to.  The WPF `TreeView` has built-in support for UI virtualization:

`<TreeView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />`

Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716882.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes it does have it built in. But this really only works if you only want to virtualize the first level (roots). Nested children are not virtualized. Using the built in virtualization also means that you need to live with the terrible scroll bar resizing behaviour too :(

Comment: Another option is to implement the `TreeView` as a `ListBox` by setting the inner margin of each item in the list based on its depth in the tree.  You'll then have to write the expand/collapse logic yourself but lists are probably easier to virtualize than trees.

Answer (score -1):

If you did not solve this issue yet, I have an idea, which I did not try: Maybe you can write your own panel to contain the tree items where you would override the MeasureOverride so that it won't get the measurement from the contained elements but rather make that calculation on its own?